# Why this template specialization for `uint64_t` doesn't match with `unsigned long` on Mac platform?

Tags: c++, templates, types, template-specialization

Why following code snippet compile failed on Mac platform using clang++?
The `sizeof` `unsigned long` and `uint64_t` is both 8, so I think they are the same type. So why the compile think the `Serializer<unsigned long>` is abstract?

Because I have define `Serializer<uint64_t>, Serializer<int64_t>, Serializer<uint32_t>, Serializer<int32_t>, Serializer<uint16_t>, Serializer<int16_t>, Serializer<uint8_t>, Serializer<int8_t>`, is there any way to resolve this issue and avoid define more type like `Serializer<unsigned long>`?

Following is the error message, both clang++ and g++ give the similar result:

> example.cpp:23:31: error: variable type 'Serializer' is
>   an abstract class
>
> ```
> Serializer<unsigned long> s;
>
>                           ^ example.cpp:6:25: note: unimplemented
> ```
>
> pure virtual method 'ToString' in 'Serializer'
>
> ```
> virtual std::string ToString(const T* val) = 0;
>
>                     ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
template <typename T>
class Serializer {
    virtual std::string ToString(const T* val) = 0;
};

template <>
class Serializer<uint64_t> {
public:

    virtual std::string ToString(const int8_t* val) {
        return "";
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // both of the size is 8 bytes
    std::cout << " size of unsigned long:" << sizeof(unsigned long) << " sizeof uint64_t:" << sizeof(uint64_t);
    // following compile error happen
    Serializer<unsigned long> s;  //<------- Error happen here
    s.ToString(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis nope, `sizeof(unsigned long)` must be _at least_ 4.

Comment: There can be different types with the same size. maybe `uint64_t` is `unsigned int`, or `unsigned long long`, or something else

Comment: The only problem that I see in your code is just not providing virtual destructor for the class templates! I tested every thing was fine on mine (gcc linx).

Comment: "*The `sizeof` `unsigned long` and `uint64_t` is both 8, so I think they are the same type*" - just because they are the same **size** does not guarantee that they are the same **type**. For instance, `uint64_t` could be `unsigned __int64` instead. You need to look at how your particular compiler's headers actually define `uint64_t`

Comment: @ZijingWu: Which version of Clang/GCC are you using? The latest versions compile this just fine.

Comment: Simply try ```std::cout << std::is_same<unsigned long, uint64_t>::value;``` by header ```<type_traits>``` to be sure! in case of inequity the result should be ```0```. Also try ```Serializer<long> s;```. and if it is OK then do the **quick fix**

Comment: @P.W  jiayuehuadeMacBook-Pro:src mi$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: @AKL, `std::is_same<unsigned long, uint64_t>::value` result is 0

Comment: So apparently they are different try other solution! was ```long``` OK? Also (I am laughing at my self ) what are the circumstances that you could not simply use ```Serializer<uint64_t> s;``` ? Give more details maybe we can give you a quick fix!

Comment: Also if you want to find out quickly what is type of ```uint64_t``` in human language, simply try ```int i; uint64_t  test = &i;``` and read the compile time error code! :) I really don't know any thing more simple than that! It should give an error along the line of ```could not assign value of type int* to ***THE TYPE*** in assignment```

Comment: @AKL, we are writing an util library, which contains `Serializer`, so it can be difficult to let the user use `uint64_t` to replace `unsigned long`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193609/discussion-between-akl-and-zijingwu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was discussed ,by using the compile-time-error-method, the type of `uint64_t` was found out to be `unsigned long long`  instead of `unsigned long`. Sizes are the same but their **names** are different and as every one knows compilers are highly sensitive to and strict about **names** and rightly so!

This can be fixed without any need to change the libraries or to change the user interface!

Just some where in between headers add something like:

```
template <>
class Serializer<unsigned long> : public Serializer<uint64_t>{};
```

Or if user can not access the `uint64_t` type  which is more likely the case:

```
template <>
class Serializer<unsigned long> : public Serializer<unsigned long long>{};
```

So now it knows that for `unsigned long` the specialization is (some what) the same as the case of `Serializer<uint64_t>` which already has been epecialized!

In addition depending on the definition of`Serializer` you might also need to add a constructor to it too like:

```
template <>
class Serializer<unsigned long> : public Serializer<unsigned long long>{
    Serializer(...DATA...):Serializer<unsigned long long>(...DATA...){}
};
```

If you don't know what is the definition, this might help:

```
//for values
class Serializer<unsigned long> : public Serializer<unsigned long long>{
    template<typename ... Ts>
    Serializer(Ts ... Vs):Serializer<unsigned long long>(Vs...){}
};

//for objects
class Serializer<unsigned long> : public Serializer<unsigned long long>{
    template<typename ... Ts>
    Serializer(const Ts& ... Os):Serializer<unsigned long long>(Os...){}
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: @ZijingWu If this helped to solve the problem please consider voting it up and/or accepting it!

Comment: @ZijingWu thanks for your question and for accepting the answer, but I wished you vote it up too :)